# Free bootstrap template not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the `cover' template to work. All I did was copy both of the files (HTML and CSS) from the folder with all the templates from getbootstrap.com and it isn't displaying like they have it on the website.

[This is what mine looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsTJc.png)

[This is what it looks like on bootstrap website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VasWN.png)

HTML:

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
            <p class="lead">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some links might be broken. Try linking these files yourself.

Comment: Have you checked font family for both the websites? It may be the case you need to load specific fonts.

Comment: bootstrap's `css` file is not included well. Check file path

Comment: Got it! The CSS link to the bootstrap.min.css file was <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">. What I did was found the bootstrap.min.css file, added it to my folder and removed the /dist/css etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove your linked files and replace them with the ones seen here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css">    

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"> 

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
          <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

  <div class="site-wrapper">

    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

      <div class="cover-container">

        <div class="masthead clearfix">
          <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inner cover">
          <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
          <p class="lead">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="mastfoot">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```